# How to know the real size of grid?

Tags: qgis, features, measurements, vector-grid

Im working with QGIS. When dividing a map with a grid I set in the paramters X=0.1 and Y=0.1. Could someone please explain what does that mean? I mean would the map be divided into 100mx100m squares? How do I know the exact measure in meters of each side of the square? Maybe its a silly question but its not that clear to me. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the units of the layers coordinate reference system.

- If you have lat/lon `degrees` like WGS84, you get grid lines every 0.1 degree (i.e. 6 minutes).
- If you have `metres` (as UTM and most other projected CRS do), your grid is every 10 centimetres.

Comment: Andre, thanks for your answer, how about for WGS84?

Comment: That should be the `degrees` case.